# Need to club request URLs into one

Tags: javascript, openlayers

We are using OpenLayers 3. Currently we are getting the layers details by sending a WMS URL similar to the below one:

```
https://xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/geoserver/pxs4gna/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Networks&TILED=true&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&SRS=EPSG%3A31370&STYLES=&BBOX=142524.123046875%2C135162.07421875%2C143067.578125%2C135705.529296875
```

Every time we select a layer, a new url is formed. Now I want to create a single URL for the same.
Currently two URLS will be formed for layers "abc" and "def":

```
https://xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/geoserver/pxs4gna/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=abc&TILED=true&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&SRS=EPSG%3A31370&STYLES=&BBOX=142524.123046875%2C135162.07421875%2C143067.578125%2C135705.529296875

https://xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/geoserver/pxs4gna/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=def&TILED=true&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&SRS=EPSG%3A31370&STYLES=&BBOX=142524.123046875%2C135162.07421875%2C143067.578125%2C135705.529296875
```

My requirement is to create

```
https://xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/geoserver/pxs4gna/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=abc,def&TILED=true&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&SRS=EPSG%3A31370&STYLES=&BBOX=142524.123046875%2C135162.07421875%2C143067.578125%2C135705.529296875
```

The below function is used to triggered when a new function is called:

```
function addLayerintoMap(layerTitle,layerName,layerWmsUrl,layerVisibilty) {

     if (layerVisibilty =='false') {
         layerVisibilty=false;
     }else {
         layerVisibilty=true;
     }
     var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
            extent: [16986,19114,295235,244940],
            resolutions: resolutionsDefined,
            tileSize: [512, 512]
          });
    //add layer into Map
    map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                  url: layerWmsUrl,
                  params: {LAYERS: layerName ,'TILED': true,VERSION: '1.1.1'},
                  tileGrid: tileGrid
                }),
        name:layerTitle,
        visible:layerVisibilty
    }));
}
```

Comment: you need to show us the code you are using to handle the selections.

Comment: @IanTurton Didn't get you. what code do you want.

Comment: "Every time we select a layer, a new url is formed." - the code that does this

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Surely for layer details you should use a GetCapabilities request, not a GetMap.

Comment: @nmtoken Can you explain me, how to use GetCapabilities

Answer (score 1):

In your function instead of creating and adding a new layer:

```
map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: layerWmsUrl,
              params: {LAYERS: layerName ,'TILED': true,VERSION: '1.1.1'},
              tileGrid: tileGrid
            }),
    name:layerTitle,
    visible:layerVisibilty
}))
```

You need to go through the existing layers and look for one where the source URL is the same as yours, then add the layer name to that sources `LAYERS` param.

Something like this:

```
layers = map.getLayers()
forEach( layer in layers){
  source = layer.getSource()
  if(source.getURL()==url){
        source.getParams('LAYERS')+=layername;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I am new to OpenLayers concept. Can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Can I request for a more detailed answer.

Comment: getURL() function is not defined. Can check on that

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html - it should be getURLs

Answer (score 0):

Try to set LAYERS or QUERY_LAYERS in [`getGetFeatureInfoUrl`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#getGetFeatureInfoUrl)

```
map.on('click', evt => {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var viewResolution = (map.getView().getResolution());


  // Optional, hence commented
  // var wmsLayersList = map.getLayers().getArray()
  //  .filter(layer => layer.getVisible())
  //  .filter(layer => {
  //    return (layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.ImageWMS || layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.TileWMS)
  //  })
  //  .map(layer => layer.getSource().getParams().LAYERS).join(',');

  var wmsLayersList = 'abc,def';
  var url = oneOfYourTwoWmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution,
    // Below EPSG projection could need to be changed with
    // your WMSprojection or your map projection
    'EPSG:3857', {
      'LAYERS': wmsLayersList
    }
  );

  console.log(url);
})
```

Comment: It is like hard coding the layer ids. My requirement here is to add the layer id every time the user checks new layer.

Comment: Updated answer in optional comment